# Это так в природе человека – искать причин(ы), верить только собственному опыту

Tags: морфология, падежи, существительные

Это так в природе человека – искать причин(ы), верить только собственному опыту.

- Можно ли употребить Р.п. в данном случае, так как речь здесь идет о причине, как о чем-то абстрактном, о каких-то, и даже неважно каких – любых, причинах. Хоть, понятно, что Р.п. наиболее часто употребляется при глаголе с отрицанием: не ищи причин.

Comment: Не смущает корявость фразы?
"Это *так* в природе человека" - так не говорят. Понятно, что вы ориентировались на выражения типа "это так по-русски", но здесь не тот случай. Такое "так" не может относиться к целому словосочетанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Искать причин" распространённое выражение, его вполне можно использовать. Приведу пару примеров:

> Это даёт нам право искать причин, влияющих на долговечность ... Химия
>   и жизнь, 1983 г.
>
> Поль Лафарг, писал: "...не в человеке, не в его свободной воле, не в
>   его нравственной и физической природе следует искать причин,
>   обусловливающих ..." Новый мир, 1972 г.
>
> Все это заставляет искать причин неблагополучного положения с
>   синтаксисом... Русский язык в школе, 1980 г.

Answer (score 0):

[**искать**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C*&all=x)

1. *кого-что*. Стараться найти, обнаружить.
   Искать нужную книгу. Искать дорогу в лесу. Искать в магазине потерявшегося ребёнка.
   // Заниматься поисками, стараться разузнать о наличии, местонахождении кого-либо, чего-либо.
   Искать работу. Милиция ищет преступника. **Искать причину болезни.**
2. *что и чего.* Стараться получить что-либо, добиться чего-либо.
   Искать правду. Искать защиту, защиты.

Второй пункт по смыслу нам не подходит (невозможно получить или добиться причины).
Я бы остановилась на том,  что грамотно использовать только винительный падеж.

*Правильнее было бы **искать причины** катастроф в рамках триады факторов...* (В. Шигин)
*Это гораздо проще, чем, например, **искать причину** трагедии в недостатках авиационного двигателя и воздушного судна* (А. Беззубцев-Кондаков).

Comment: *невозможно получить или добиться причины* — Вы ошибаетесь. Можно "добиваться причины" (в ед. числе) или "добиваться причин" (во мн. числе). Гугл находит сотни цитат самых именитых авторов.